# Flashed my Android and now I can't display arabic, Hebrew

Tags: rom-flashing, backup, languages

I followed this [tuto](http://android.wonderhowto.com/how-to/get-all-new-iphone-marshmallow-emojis-almost-any-android-device-0166907/) to flash a zip to my phone (S3 mini - Android 4.4.4 )  using flashfire to show the new emojis. All seems to work well though I noticed Arabic and many other languages are not displayed I only see boxes.

Is there any way to fix it knowing that I skipped the backup step.

Comment: This is the reason you DON'T skip backups. Just flash the stock firmware back with Odin.

Comment: Yea I flashed the ROM again and everything works fine now. Next time I'll do a backup ! Thank you

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer so it can help other people? http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue all you need is to flash the firmware ROM. I was using a custom ROM so I used CWM recovery to install it. Here's a [link](http://www.digitalreborn.com/install-custom-rom-cwm-recovery/) that could help but DON'T wipe data/reset factory, otherwise you will lose all your data.